# Tauri message not being sent from backend

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rust, tauri

I'm trying to run a function which will fetch JSON data when the window loads.

Here's what I'm calling App() in App.tsx

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = listen("loaded", (event) => {
      console.log(event.payload);
      readFileContents();
    });
    return () => {
      unlisten.then(f => f());
    }
  }, [] );
```

and here's my main function in main.rs:

```rust
fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .setup(|app| {
            
            app.emit_all("loaded", Payload { message: "Tauri is awesome!".into() }).unwrap();
            Ok(())
        })
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![])
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

Comment: And? Does the code fail to compile? With what error? Does it compile but fail to run? With what error? Does it compile and run but produce the wrong result? What result did you expect and what did it produce instead?

Comment: If you send events from the setup hook without any conditions (aka, do something in a spawned thread for X time, then send event) the javascript side won't have had a change to run completely yet, meaning the event will get lost.